# Akka: How to read config from within a non-actor object

Tags: scala, akka, config

In akka, it's easy to read the global config via system.settings.config if in an actor.

However, if I have a plain singleton object which needs to read the config from the actorSystem, how should I do?

Assuming I don't want do use configFactory to do the same config file parse/fallback again.

Thanks

Leon

Comment: If you have a reference to the `ActorSystem` itself, then it's as easy as `system.settings.config` (assuming the ref is called `system`).  If you don't have a ref to the `ActorSystem` then not sure what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As cmbaxter said, if you have a reference to the actor system, use that, if you don't, well, maybe you could change your code so that you would have a reference to it. If that is impossible, then you could read the config using configFactory and put somewhere your singleton has access and also use that configuration as a parameter to the actor system when you create that instead of letting it read the config from disk.

```
object MyConfig {
  private val myConfig = ??? // however you want to load your config
  private val regularConfig = ConfigFactory.load();

  // now you can access it from anywhere you want
  val config = myConfig.withFallback(regularConfig);
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
val system = ActorSystem("my-system", MyConfig.config)
```

Comment: In fact, it's a completely stand-alone zero-dependencies library: https://github.com/typesafehub/config